# What extension to enable in order to use scandir() in php?

Tags: php

I read from the php documentation that since 5.1.0 scandir() is by default not usable in php.

How can i enable it?

Comment: btw, is this an actual problem you have, or something you have read about on the internet? In other words, did you try on *your* machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On the documentation page](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), I don't see anything to support your claim - the only reference to version is "(PHP 5)", and `scandir()` is a built-in function, so you don't need an additional extension for it.

(Anyway, the docs page has a long list of alternative approaches and/or improvements.)

Answer (score 1):

Where does it say that in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)?

Have you tried using it?

If it doesn't work, you can probably use `glob()`.